# qtreeview test if item is checkable

Tags: python, pyside, qtreeview

How can I test whether an item is checkable in a QTreeview in python/pyside?

```
def set_selected_shots(self, state=None):
    checkstate = QtCore.Qt.Checked if state else QtCore.Qt.Unchecked
    selected_rows = self.ui_shots.selectionModel().selectedRows()

    for idx in selected_rows:
        model = idx.model()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `QStandardItemModel` then you must use the `itemFromIndex()` method that if you provide the index returns the item, and then check the state with the `checkState()` method:

```
selected_rows = self.ui_shots.selectionModel().selectedRows()
for idx in selected_rows:
    item = idx.model().itemFromIndex(idx)
    if item.isCheckable():
        if item.checkState() == Qt.Checked:
            print("checked")
        else:
            print("unchecked")
```